# Spring\Tomcat redirect to angular page on 404 error

Tags: spring, angular, tomcat, web.xml

I have an application written in Spring (rest api) and deployed on Tomcat. On the same context exists angular 4 application using this api. I would like to redirect all 404 errors to error page in angular app. I managed to redirect all url in pattern `\app\#\some\url` by using appropriate angular route. But this those not help with url like `\app\some\url` which are not handled by angular. In case of such url Tomcat returns it's default page. I managed to redirect all 404 error to angular main page by using following code in web.xml file.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
</error-page>
```

But when I changed `/` for `/#/404` (error page form angular app) and tried to access non-existent url I just get blank page instead of redirection. Is there a way to configure my app or server to redirect to this error page? Or do I have to copy this page and put it in WEB-INF so I can use it as static page? I would like to avoid second option as in this case I have to duplicate this page and in case of changes remember about both of them.

Comment: what's the result of directing visit the /#/404 page

Comment: As I wrote. In case I change value in location tag to `/#/404` Tomcat returns empty 404 response on non-existent url and does nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

1) Using hash # in URLs will solve your problem.
2) Another solution would be to have a rewrite rule on your Apache or ngnix servers so that they redirect to index everytime.

Comment: 1) I'm already using # in angular urls. Directly going to `\app\#\404` works properly. 2) I just want to redirect 404 errors, not all requests.

Answer (score 0):

it is because in web.xml,the location it's to track down the file. So the value you put in here must be a file path.

My perspective, you can use a jsp to redirect the user into the actual uri path /#/404.

Comment: I will give it a try and post result later. Maybe that is the way to go.